# Using array index on FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an array of objects as follows. None of the objects has a unique key.

```
[
   {
       data1: "text1",
       data2: "text2"
   },
   {
       data1: "text3",
       data2: "text4"
   }
]
```

I have a FlatList defined as follows:

```
<FlatList

     data={this.state.items}
     renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

I have also tried adding:

```
 keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
```

but I still get the same message. I am not sure what the above `this._keyExtractor` is supposed to be doing. Is it a built in function to pull the index or a function that I am supposed to create myself?

What am I doing wrong and how can I just use the array index as my unique key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you copy `keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}` from [ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) website. You forgot to copy the function to your file.

```
_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;
```

Or you just copy the function and paste in `keyExtrator`

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.items}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 9):

[`keyExtractor`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#keyextractor) already calculates the array indices for the data that you provide to it.

Therefore if you want to use array indices as the unique element then you can do

```
<FlatList 
      data={this.state.items}
      renderItem={this.renderItem} //... toString() since it accepts string elements
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround:

I had to take my items array and insert a unique index into each object in the `key` property as follows:

```
items.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.key = i.toString()
})
```

Once loaded into state, then I simply used my original code:

```
<FlatList
     data={this.state.items}
     renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

Note: I needed to use toString, otherwise I got the error `Warning : Failed child context type: Invalid child context 'virtualizedCell.cellKey' of type 'number' supplied to 'CellRenderer', expected 'string'`. Once I used toString, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`keyExtractor={(item) => 'VI' + item.id}`

VI is any string you want

Comment: Could you provide more details about your answer please?